# WooCommerce order-received endpoint and the order object

Tags: woocommerce

I am using the conditional is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') in my header to check to see if the the 'page' is the Order Recieved end point, and if so I add some additional code to my Facebook Pixel code.

However I would like to access the order object as well so I can get the total of the order as well as check to see if it is actually complete ( get_status() ).

How can I access the order object from the order received end point?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me

```
$order_key = $_GET['key'];
$order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key($order_key);
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
```

Comment: It works great, thanks! To include a check on whether the key is set in $_GET: `if ( isset( $_GET['key'] ) && $order_id = wc_get_order_id_by_order_key( $_GET['key'] ) ) { $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); }`